# When I run 'mongod' command in command prompt, the messages are being displayed in json form. How to fix it?

Tags: mongodb, windows-10, command-prompt

This is what is being displayed after I run "mongod". Everything works fine, just the issue of not being able to read the messages clearly due to this format, is there a way to change the format to where the messages are just displayed line by line?
[image: ** **]

Comment: You can log the messages to a log file, and query the logs using a useful tool: [mtools for MongoDB](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools). Also, see general info about the [Log Messages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/) for MongoDB v4.4.

Answer (score 1):

I read in the documentation that this is how log messages will be displayed starting from v4.4 of mongodb.

It appears to be the case and a way to improve readability is by pretty-printing the file using 'jq' utility ( JSON processor )